# Validar que un número sea entero

Tags: php, script

hace poco que he empezado con php y tengo una duda tonta, pero que no me deja realmente avanzar. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario introduce un valor que no sea entero como un "2.2" pues salga un mensaje de error. Pero cada vez que introduzco un valor me sale incorrecto. Pero si intento pintar por ejemplo argv[2] con el número que ha introducido el usuario lo pinta perfectamente. No entiendo:

```
if($argv[1]<0){
    echo "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0";
}else if(!is_int($argv[2])){
    echo "Incorrecto introduce un valor entero";
}else {
    echo "correcto";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es `$argv`, un array en el que quieres verificar los índices `1` y `2`
?

Comment: si, por lo que nos han dicho tiene que ser así. El primer numero que me comprueba lo hace bien, el segundo no me lo valida. Igualmente si paso argv[2] a una variable como $cantidad me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Qué vale `$argv[1]` y `$argv[2]` cuando dices que no funciona como esperas?

Comment: En plan ejecuto el script desde la terminal donde introduzco los valores, $argv[0] es el nombre del archivo, $argv[1] es el primer numero que en este caso es un dos y me lo valida y en el $argv[2] intento validar que sea un numero entero para que no entren decimales y es el que falla.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($argv);`, pues me parece que estará tomando un espacio o algo. A mi me funciona.

Comment: Me sigue pasando, no entiendo, tu lo tienes exactamente igual ?

Comment: Esta prueba a mano: `$argv = array(0, 2, 2);

if($argv[1]<0){
    echo "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0";
}else if(!is_int($argv[2])){
    echo "Incorrecto introduce un valor entero";
}else {
    echo "correcto";
}` muestra `correcto` como resultado. ¿Qué te muestra el `var_dump($argv);`?

Comment: Lo que yo creo es que tu variable se parece a esto: `$argv = array(0, 2, " 2");` en ese caso sí mostraría `Incorrecto ....`

Comment: Prueba así: `if($argv[1]<0){
    echo "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0";
}else if(!is_int((int)$argv[2])){
    echo "Incorrecto introduce un valor entero";
}else {
    echo "correcto";
}` forzando a entero el segundo valor.

Comment: Eso probe yo antes intentando forzarlo, pero me dice lo mismo. He probado con el código que me has pasado y lo mismo no entiendo el porque. Si hago el var_dump antes me los muestra como string, si lo pongo despues de ejecutar el código me los muestra como int o si no el segundo valor como float.

Comment: Comparte la salida del `var_dump` please.

Comment: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  string(2) " 2"
}

Comment: Es lo que sospechaba, el segundo argumento lo está asumiendo como una cadena, con un espacio en blanco delante. Puedes probar con `ctype_digit()` y a la vez `trim()` para limpiar el espacio. Algo así: `if($argv[1]<0){
    echo "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0";
}else if(!ctype_digit(trim($argv[2]))){
    echo "Incorrecto introduce un valor entero";
}else {
    echo "correcto";
}`

Comment: Ahora si que me lo hace, tengo otra duda en caso de hacer un argv[3] o querer meter un argv[2] en otra variable para realizar un calculo, tambien necesito aplicar el trim y ctype_digit ? Muchas gracias

Comment: El `trim()` sí, sin ninguna duda. Y `ctype_digit()` depende de para qué quieras el dato. [Revisa lo que hace esa función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ctype-digit.php) y podrás decidir si la necesitas o no para un eventual argumento `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la salida del `var_dump` mostrada aquí:

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> int(0) 
    [1]=> int(2) 
    [2]=> string(2) " 2" 
}
```

Podemos ver claramente que el argumento en el índice `2` es una cadena (está asumiendo como argumento dos todo lo que se escriba luego del argumento uno).

Para hacer la comprobación tienes entonces que limpiar el dato con [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) y puedes usar [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ctype-digit.php) para la verificación numérica.

El código quedaría así:

```
if($argv[1]<0){
     echo "El precio no puede ser inferior a 0";
}else if(!ctype_digit(trim($argv[2]))){
     echo "Incorrecto introduce un valor entero";
}else{
     echo "correcto";
}
```